# Issues with Former Academic Advisor

Tags: advisor, undergraduate

I'm currently a sophomore in undergraduate college who is just recently became a business administration major and I was undeclared for my freshman year and part of my sophomore year. Once my old advisor signed my paperwork about changing majors, I asked him when I would be graduating since I was genuinely curious and to reaffirm a fact that he said in an earlier appointment that I would graduate in the winter semester. However, he stated that I would need a fifth year and proceeded to harshly demand why I took classes in CJA, education, and had taken other gen ed's. When I reminded him that he did say I would graduate in the winter semester, he did not believe me and told me to give up on graduating in the spring with my other fellow classmates. I explained to my former advisor my reasons why I took said classes, because I was undeclared, yet he refused to believe me. To be honest, I was caught off guard by his behavior since in my last appointment with him, he was cordial and polite towards me. After my appointment with him, I began to lose self confidence in my choice for this major and I was confused by his harsh attitude towards me. After that harsh exchange, I transferred to a new advisor who is helpful and keeps me motivated but I am still bothered because I do not know why did my former advisor decide to say those harsh words to me. Any ideas behind my former advisor's behavior?

Comment: When he said you would graduate "in winter semester", was this based on a specific plan as to what classes you would need to take and when?  Did you double-check this plan against the graduation requirements in the catalog, and the schedule of planned course offerings?  Did you stick to the plan?

Comment: He probably had no idea when you could graduate and hadn't bothered to check / make a plan for the new major.

Comment: He said I would graduate in the winter semester judging by the classes I am taking in the fall semester which are all classes for this major and due to how much credits I have taken over the course of my college. Thanks for pointing that out Nate!

Comment: Why do you assume we know what "_CJA_" is? -1.

Comment: CJA is Criminal Justice, I do apologize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Any ideas behind my former advisor's behavior?

Maybe he is a bozo. Maybe he had a bad day. Maybe he misunderstood the situation. What does it matter? You have found a new advisor and moved on with your life.

I would have just voted to close ("help me guess what he was thinking" questions are off-topic here), but I think there is a real issue in your post, and I think it's this line:

> I asked him when I would be graduating since I was genuinely curious

You should not be "asking" this question! As you've discovered, advisors make mistakes all the time -- it's very common for undergraduate students to stay longer than they expected (and pay extra) because their advisor made a mistake. Instead, you should look up all the classes you need for your major (including gen eds) and make a plan for when you will take each of them. Your advisor (the good one) can help you with this, but any mistakes will hurt you, not your advisor, so it's on you to get this right.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I really do appreciate it! The only reason why I asked was to have a rough estimate of when I will graduate.

Answer (score 0):

I can think  of  ONE  reason,  no  TWO  reasons  for  this  kind  of  behavior.  Business  administration  is  a  DEGREE PROGRAM, NOT  A MAJOR,.  is  the  first  reason.   You   are   going  to HAVE  to   declare  a  major OFFICIALLY  in   B.B.A  degree  program  at  some  point.

Maybe  he  honestly  forgot   he  told you that   you  would    graduate  in   the  "winter'  semester.   but  there   really  is NO SUCH THING   as  winter  semester  on  semester   academic  calendar.     there   are   winter  QUARTERS..  There   are  Fall   spring   and   simmer   semesters.   Not  ALL  colleges  have  commencement  (graduation)  ceremonies  for  all   semesters  or  quarters.I   graduated  from  graduate   school  on  July   29.   i WALKED   commencement  in  MAY   because  i had  successfully  orally  defended  my master's  thesis.  but  i  did NOT  graduate  until  i handed  in  the  library copies  of my  master's  thesis  into  the  graduate  college.

IF you  changed  your ENTIRE   DEGREE PROGRAM.  you need  to  ask  THAT   academic  adviser   when  you   can  graduate.   and you also need  to  ask   WHEN and  how  to officially  DECLARE  a major, management    accounting,  m,   finance  or  information  systems in  that  degree program.

Business  administration IS NOT A MAJOR.

YOU   are  the one   who is  responsible  for  seeing  that you  take ALL  the  courses  for your  DEGREE PROGRAM   and   WHEN you  take  those   courses to  determine  WHEN you  can  graduate,  Your academic  adviser  or  advisers  is NOT   responsible  for  this.

Academic   advisers  are human  beings  too.    You have  NO IDEA   what  they  go home  too.  most  families  have  at  least  ONE   dysfunctional    family member   and  sometimes MORE  than  one.  There  can  be  handicapped   children  or  grand  children   as  well.   I  should  know,  because  i  was   a university  faculty  dependent,   and  iv'e  been   type  1  diabetic   since  I  was  2  years  old. SOME   faculty  are  homeless.

Talk   to your  current  academic  adviser   as  soon  as  possible  and  ask   when  and how  to  officially  declare  a major.

Comment: A lot depends on where the original poster goes to school. Some places do have "Business Administration" as an undergraduate major in itself. Some places have a (shorter) winter term in addition to the fall and spring semesters. But you're universally right that "Academic advisers are human beings too." :)